# I want all my service to run through my new user

Tags: ssh, services, linux-headers, dash-shell

This can be a long because i am very new to this linux so please help me with this, i created a new user using `sudo adduser newUser sudo` now i want all my services should run through this newUser, maybe by default all services run through root user, i also set a password for root using `sudo passwd root`, i listed the user using `service --status-all` it displayed several list i don't know which service is running through which user, but at last i want some specific service to run through my newUser, i know i have to write shell script but how should i start ?

Thanks

Comment: Danger! Don't do this until you make yourself more knowledgeable about Linux. Don't ever do this.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator for replying me but i have to do this, can you please send me a link so that i come to know more about this, it will be very help full.